# Removing a search index component SP2016

Tags: search, index-component

I have a SP2016 farm with 2 index servers. Since I have a lot of data on the farm, I wanted to remove the index from the C: Drive to another drive with more space.

I went ahead an followed this article.
https://www.totalsol.com/how-to-move-a-sharepoint-search-index/

Using the following commands

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication “Search Service Application”
$instance=Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Local
$current=Get-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -SearchApplication $ssa

$clone=New-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Clone -SearchApplication $ssa SearchTopology $current

New-SPEnterpriseSearchIndexComponent -SearchTopology $clone -IndexPartition 0 -SearchServiceInstance $instance -RootDirectory “E:\NewIndexLocation”

Set-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Identity $clone

Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Identity $current
```

I got a new index, but somehow the old index was not removed.
In my search application it currently looks like this.
[image]

I have tried to use the following

```
$comp=Get-SPEnterpriseSearchComponent -SearchTopology $clone | ? {$_.Name -eq “IndexComponent1”}
Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchComponent -Identity $comp -SearchTopology $clone
```

But without any luck.
How do I remove the index the duplicated index ?

Comment: did my answer help you or do you need any assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this you must do `$comp.Activate()` for activating this Topology and it will take some time.

If it doesn't work, create whole new Topology and Activate it.